# Where is fetched data saved in React?

Tags: reactjs, fetch

I am trying to understand this snipped of code at an intrinsic level:

```
fetchAllData(){
    fetch('http://ec2-x-x-xx-xx.xx-west-x.compute.amazonaws.com:3001/', {mode: "no-cors"})
    .then(res => {
        return res.json();
    })
```

to better understand a simple component like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchAllData();
}

fetchAllData(){
    fetch('http://ecx-x-x-xxx-xx.xx-west-x.compute.amazonaws.com:3001/', {mode: "no-cors"})
    .then(res => {
        return res.json();
    })
    .then(resJson => {
        this.setState(prevState => {
            return{
                fetchDataLoaded: true,
                fetchData: resJson.data.todolist,
            };
        });
    });
}
```

- When fetching from an API, is the data stored temporarily in the `res
  =>` function and chained on using `.then`?
- If so, how could I visualise (in the console maybe?) the properties of the data fetched?

I find myself in a position where I need to manipulate data pulled from an API I don't know the shape of.

I am new to React and any detailed explanation would help a lot, thank you.

Comment: In the second `.then` `resJson => console.log(resJson)` would help you.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a react thing at all, but rather plain javascript and promises. `fetch` returns a resolved promise. The response isn't "saved" in res, per se, but rather is passed to a function where you've named the parameter `res`. If you want to view the raw response `res` you can do that in the first chained `then`, ensuring you still return the json promise for the next thenable.

```
fetch('http://ec2-3-8-196-93.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:3001/', {mode: "no-cors"})
  .then(res => {
    console.log('res', res);
    return res.json();
  })
```

Perhaps it would be a little clearer broken down a bit. Factor out the anonymous inline function into a named one, and pass *that* as the thenable callback. The fetch result isn't really saved anywhere (it *is* technically in memory in the browser heap, but that's another topic) and is just being passed to a function.

```
const logResultAndReturnJson = result => {
  console.log('result', result);
  return result.json();
};

fetch('http://ec2-3-8-196-93.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:3001/', {mode: "no-cors"})
  .then(logResultAndReturnJson)
```

If you need to manipulate the fetched data, then you likely want to look at the resolved JSON object *and not* the response object.

Answer (score 1):

In the given example, the variable `resJson` contains the response body parsed by JSON(i.e. this piece of code only works if the API returns a JSON response).

Adding on to @drew, This `.then(...).then(...)` is called Promise Chaining. It is a useful way of making a flow where you can process data in stages and then deal with errors in the end.

As Reference, these two pages will surely help

1. [promise-basics](https://javascript.info/promise-basics)
2. [promise-chaining](https://javascript.info/promise-chaining)